# EhCache, JPA 2.0 L2 cache, Caching strategy

Tags: java, caching, jpa-2.0, ehcache, distributed-caching

HI all,

I'm new to the world of L2 Caching so please go easy on me :). I have a few questions:

**1) What would be the difference between EhCache vs JPA 2.0 L2 Cache?**

To my understanding, EhCache is distributed (can also be stand-alone), while JPA 2.0 L2 Cache is not (per JVM).

**2) Caching Strategy**

Please share your caching 101 strategy. How to cache collection (issues and tips)? How to search an object in your cache pool (if you know you're caching it).

**3) Caching and Stored Procedures**

Let's say the database supports 2 different applications on top of it. How would one solve update problem when one application updates the data via Stored Procedure, while the other (cache) reads it? To the reader, it is as if there is no update.

I heard stories that certain big websites cache everything. Does this mean they write their own data access layer on top of both their cache library and their JPA / ORM?

PS: I understand that the golden rule is to avoid caching early on or better yet to increase the hardware capability. I'm asking this question for learning purposes. I'm also not asking for a specific scenario, but more of the general rule, general scenario, lowest common denominator, it doesn't have to solve everybody's problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

1) EHCache is a caching implementation. JPA2 L2 is a caching interface. You can use EHCache as your JPA L2 cache provider. The L2 cache provider that you pick should depend entirely on your requirements. If you think EHCache is the best fit, then use it.

2) I'm going to leave this as it's a bit vague. There are many good strategies for many different scenarios.

3) If you have something that's updating your database and not hitting your cache, then your cache will become stale. If that's okay in your domain, then fine. Otherwise, you'll need to come up with a different solution to either your caching or updating needs so that they both remain in sync.